# Setting dictionary property value to be the same as a previous value

Tags: python

I have a dictionary which I'd like to create a key/value pair where the value is the same as a previous property.

Is there a way I can assign `property2`'s value to be the same as `property1` without repeating myself?

```
obj = {
  'property1': 'abc',
  'property2': 'abc'
}
```

I tried this:

```
obj = {
  'property1': 'abc',
  'property2': obj['property1']
}
```

But that is referencing `obj` before it's assigned.

Answer (score 0):

u can store the value in a variable first and then assign it like:

```
value = 'abc'

obj = {
  'property1': value,
  'property2': value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a value to a dictionary, you can do it in a few ways:

## List Comprehension:

```
d = {a:'abc' for a in list('abcdefghijk')}
```

This will assign `'abc'` to all keys in the dictionary.

The output of this will be:

```
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'abc', 'c': 'abc', 'd': 'abc', 'e': 'abc', 'f': 'abc', 'g': 'abc', 'h': 'abc', 'i': 'abc', 'j': 'abc', 'k': 'abc'}
```

## Assign to variable:

**(like Marcos highlighted in earlier post)**

value = 'abc'

```
d = {a:value for a in list('abcdefghijk')}
```

Same result:

```
{'a': 'abc', 'b': 'abc', 'c': 'abc', 'd': 'abc', 'e': 'abc', 'f': 'abc', 'g': 'abc', 'h': 'abc', 'i': 'abc', 'j': 'abc', 'k': 'abc'}
```